# Good Intercept survey platform/partners

Tags: software-development, web-development, analytics

I was wondering if anyone could suggest **best/good intercept survey platforms for both Web & App**. I am scoping for a survey platform that lets me run intercept on nuanced triggers like time spent on a page, scrolling behaviour, clicks, source, pathways etc.

What are you currently using? And any pro & cons you discovered on your own research?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Anamika